# How to return a value from custom action script in a VS2008 setup project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, custom-action

I'm creating a setup project and I need to execute a VBScript file as a custom action, but I don't know how to return a value from the script to the installation. I need to do this, because I want to decide in the script whether the installation should continue or fail.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to call (From the custom action script)

```
Err.Raise YourErrorCode
```

This should stop your setup with a failure.